# Does the ember.js router support multiple params from different routes simultaneously?

Tags: ember.js

http://jsfiddle.net/BBt2h/1/

The above jsfiddle shows a simple ember.js app that allows you to

- paginate your content
- sort by a column
- filter your content by typing

> pagination route urls look like this /foo/#/page/2
>
> sort route urls look like this /foo/#/sort/id
>
> filter route urls look like this /foo/#/search/text

TL;DR => It's a simple mixin that helps you sift through a lot of data found in your ArrayController

The routes setup looks something like this

```
PersonApp.Router.map(function(match) {
    this.resource("person", { path: "/" }, function() {
        this.route("page", { path: "/page/:page_id" });
        this.route("search", { path: "/search/:page_term" });
        this.route("sort", { path: "/sort/:page_column" });
    });
});

PersonApp.PersonSortRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('person').set('sortBy', model);
  },
  model: function(params) {
    return PersonApp.Page.create({column: params.page_column});
  }
});

PersonApp.PersonSearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('person').set('filterBy', model.get('term'));
  },
  model: function(params) {
    return PersonApp.Page.create({term: params.page_term});
  },
  serialize: function(model) {
    return { page_term: model.term };
  }
});

PersonApp.PersonPageRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return PersonApp.Person.find(params.page_id);
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this.controllerFor('person').set('selectedPage', model.get('id'));
    }
});

PersonApp.PersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return PersonApp.Person.find();
    }
});
```

The basics of my problem

1.) user clicks on the page 2 link and the url changes to

/foo/#/page/2

2.) that same user then decides to sort by username instead of the default id so they click username

/foo/#/sort/username

**now I've lost the page, but my content still has a selectedPage of 2 (from the pagination)

3.) finally they decide to filter the list down using the search / filter

/foo/#/search/dave (after they type 4 letters)

**now I've lost the sort param and the page param (yet the state is set on the controller)

The problem here is that I need the ability to copy a url for page #2 after I decided to sort by username and filter everything by the work "dave" - and paste it in an email to a co-worker so they can see the exact results I see now ... but as you can tell my url does not reflect all the state anymore.

In addition, the back button does as expected because I've lost some context after each url change.

How can I construct my routes to achieve this (assuming the RC1 router api supports this at all) ?

I had something like this working before the new router was merged in (early Jan 2013)

**UPDATE**

It looks like [alexspeller](https://twitter.com/alexspeller) has a custom mixin that will accomplish this today

Here is the [project](https://github.com/alexspeller/ember-query) github page, and [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1773) is the open issue for the emberjs project on github